# ssh -t keeps asking for password on gitlab server hosted with docker on a vps

Tags: linux, git, docker, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to build a webserver in which i can assign certain branches of repo's to different domains so that i can easily test and deploy to my live webapps. So at this moment, i have 3 docker containers running (Mysql, PHPMyAdmin and Gitlab). I managed to setup Gitlab to take over my repo hosted at Github and now i am trying to be able to commit changes to my vpn hosted repo. However it seems that even though my key is set-up and recognised, i still get a password prompt.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 with Docker 19.03.1. I am connecting through a Windows 7 machine cmd terminal. I am planning to run several different sites with different domains on this server.

"docker ps" returns the following:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx        gitlab/gitlab-ce        "/assets/wrapper"        45 hours ago        Up 45 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30022->30022/tcp   gitlab
xxxxxxxxxxxx        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 days ago          Up 2 days               0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp                                                         phpmyadmin
xxxxxxxxxxxx        mysql:8.0.1             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago          Up 2 days               3306/tcp                                                                     mysql-server
```

If i run "ssh -Tv" git@gitlab.myserver.net i get the following result:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.myserver.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.myserver.net:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:SOMERANDOMSTRINGOFCHARACTERS 
debug1: Host 'gitlab.myserver.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: My Name and Last name RSA SHA256:SOMERANDOMSTRINGOFCHARACTERS  agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: My First and Last Name RSA SHA256:SOMERANDOMSTRINGOFCHARACTERS agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

It seems that it tries to offer the registered key that i have stored in my user agent (i offer this through pageant). However right after it has checked every possible location for a key, and decided that it either wants to authenticate with the key or a password, it just skips past the key and prompts me for a password.

I tried several different key types that are supported by GitLab, i tried putting "ssh://" in front of the path but that just makes it unable to connect to the server whatsoever. And i tried searching in the GitLab and Docker documentation, and all over SO and other troubleshoot sites for similar problems, but i can't seem to find a similar situation. What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: What key are you expecting it to use to authenticate? Where is that key stored?

Comment: I am using a key that is authenticated through pageant. The key is stored in /users/user/.ssh/. The line `debug1: Offering public key: My First and Last Name RSA SHA256:SOMERANDOMSTRINGOFCHARACTERS agent ` indicate that it has found this key and offers it to the server.

Comment: Okay, well like you said, your client offered the key to the server and the server didn't accept it. Then the client looked for all of the default keys, didn't find any of them, and moved on to the password authentication method.

Comment: That much is clear to me. The question is more as to why the key isn't accepted. It has been configured in gitlab, which it is directly addressing. I got some tips that it might have something to do that the container does not have the right persmission to write files somewhere, but that is something i am now trying to find out.